# What is the complexity of T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + 1, Given T(1) = 1

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science

I attempted to solve this using substitution ->

T(n)   = 2*T(n/2) + 1

T(n/2) = 2*T(n/4) + 1

Eventually I get to:

(2^3)T( n/8 ) + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0

Or

(2^i)T(n/(2^i)) + 2^(i-1)

I'm not sure how to go from here (assuming what I have so far is correct)

Any help greatly appreciated and apologies for the crappy formatting

EDIT:

Using the master theory

a* T(n/b) + c(n^k)

I arrive at:

T(n) = n ^ (log2) [log base is 2]

O(n)

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer, still looking for help thank you!

Comment: The conditions only uniquely determine $T(n)$ for $n$ a power of two. Namely, if $n$ is a power of two, then $T(n)$ must be one less than the next higher power of two after $n$, or $2n-1$. One must also define $T$ at other odd numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 
you don't know the answer,
you can argue like this:

$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
$.

Let $n = 2^m$ to get
$T(2^m) 
= 2T(2^m/2)+ 1
= 2T(2^{m-1})+ 1
$.

Let $T(2^m) = U(m)
$.
$U(0) = T(2^0) = 1
$.
Then
$U(m) = 2U(m-1)+1
$.
The values of $U$ are
$1, 3, 7, 15, ...$

Looks like 
$U(m)
=2^{m+1}-1
$.

(See below if not sure
how to get this.)

If true for $m-1$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
U(m)
&=2U(m-1)+1\\
&=2(2^{m}-1)+1\\
&=2^{m+1}-2+1\\
&=2^{m+1}-1\\
\end{array}
$

which completes the proof by induction.

Therefore
$T(2^m) = U(m)
=2^{m+1}-1
=2\cdot 2^m-1
$

so
$T(n) = 2n-1
$
for $n$ a power of 2.

---

If
$U(m) = 2U(m-1)+1
$,
divide by $2^m$ to get
$\dfrac{U(m)}{2^m} 
= \dfrac{2U(m-1)+1}{2^m}
= \dfrac{U(m-1)}{2^{m-1}}+\dfrac{1}{2^m}
$.

Let 
$V(m) = \dfrac{U(m)}{2^m}
$,
so that
$V(m) = V(m-1)+\dfrac{1}{2^m}
$
or
$V(m) - V(m-1)
=\dfrac{1}{2^m}
$.

This telescopes, and we get

$\begin{array}\\
V(n)-V(0)
&\sum_{m=1}^n (V(m) - V(m-1))\\
&\sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{1}{2^m}\\
&=1-\dfrac1{2^n}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\dfrac{U(m)}{2^m}-\dfrac{U(0)}{2^0}
=V(m)-V(0)
=1-\dfrac1{2^m}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
U(m)
&=2^m(U(0)+1-\dfrac1{2^m})\\
&=2^m(1+1-\dfrac1{2^m})\\
&=2^{m+1}-1\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

The line under Or is incorrect in that the constant should be $2^i-1$, not $2^{i-1}$.  You have essentially proposed that for $n=2^i$ you have $T(n)=2^i+2^i-1=2n-1$.  You should now prove that by induction.  Assume that $T(2^k)=2^{k+1}-1$ and show that $T(2^{k+1})=2^{k+2}-1$ by using the definition you are given.

Note that like many of these problems the definition of $T(n)$ only tells us what it is for $n$ a power of $2$.  If you try to compute $T(3)$ you get stuck because you don't know $T(\frac 32)$.  The setter really should say they only care about powers of $2$ or tell you how to handle the fractions.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why/how it should be 2^i - 1, could you point me in the right direction for how I can solve these types of problems?

Comment: The sum of all the powers of $2$ up to $2^{i-1}$ is $2^i-1$ and you have that sum in the line above.  For example, $1+2+4=7=2^3-1$